# SmartIrc4net Disconnects After a While

Tags: .net, irc

I got SmartIrc4net to connect to FreeNode, and it works great, but after a while the bot just disconnects out of nowhere.  Any ideas on why this might happen?

Error message:

IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond aftera  period of time, or established connected failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: http://smartirc4net.meebey.net/docs/0.4.0/html/Meebey.SmartIrc4net.IrcConnection.OnDisconnected.html what does this event say?

Comment: try compiling the lib from source and see if there's an exception thrown by the tcp connection. Deep down in there there must be an explanation for the disconnect.

Comment: I managed to track down the exception, and added the message to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Study the IRC protocol. I am sure you have to PING the server every minute or so from the client.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was only the server doing the pings, but I went ahead and pinged it every 30 seconds anyway and it appears to work again.  Thanks.